# why the employee_id are coming as `###########` instead of numbers as they put in the text files?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two text files as below:

***Project2.txt***

```
77;445;John;55
78;445;John;50
79;445;John;65
```

***Project1.txt***

```
80;447;John;35
81;447;John;45
84;447;John;51
```

Now i have created one ***External table*** as below:

```
CREATE TABLE WORKING_HOURS_EXT
( employee_id       NUMBER(8), 
  project_id        VARCHAR2(20),
  Ename        VARCHAR2(25), 
  Durations         VARCHAR2(25)
) 
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
( 
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY xtern_data_dir 
  ACCESS PARAMETERS 
  ( 
    records delimited by newline 
    fields terminated by ';'  
  ) 
  LOCATION ('Project2.txt', 'Project1.txt') 
) 
PARALLEL;
```

But now my confusion is why the ***employee_id*** are coming as `###########` instead of numbers as they put in the text files?

```
SQL> set linesize 50
SQL> column employee_id format a5;
SQL> column project_id format a10;
SQL> column Ename format a10;
SQL> column Durations format a10;
SQL> select * from WORKING_HOURS_EXT;

EMPLOYEE_ID PROJECT_ID ENAME      DURATIONS
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 ########## 447        John       35
 ########## 447        John       45
 ########## 447        John       51
 ########## 445        John       55
 ########## 445        John       50
 ########## 445        John       65

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Why are you forcing a text formatting  on a number column?

Comment: Otherwise rows are not coming in a single line, so i tried. But what the reason can you logically explained?

Comment: What happens if you use `column employee_id format 99999` instead?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yeah! it worked. can you put it as your answer,so that I can accept it and give vote to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [SQL*Plus User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1081036), numbers should be formatted like:

```
column employee_id format 99999
```

... not forced to an alphanumeric format wirh `A5`.